# Php - code to disappear after month

Tags: php

I have a code which displays hint for users, f.e.

```
echo "Please read a new rulebook";
```

And is there a way in php to add code which will delete this hint after a month (so I will not have to delete it manually myself?) ?

Comment: Why not use : `database` , and store this value in database , along with the expiry date.? , and then if the date is over, don't show the text , and when page is loaded, just delete it from database

Comment: take a look at the Date() function http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php, don't just ask for code. try to doe it yourself and if it doesn't work you can ask it here.

Comment: @Arsh You don't need a database for this task. Unless you already have some generalised notification message mechanism which you want to dynamically configure through a database, that would just be overkill.

Comment: @deceze the text seemed to be something that might be an regular alert for the users about something new on the website , so basically , for future things , he can just go for database and just need to add new value into the database which will auto manage it self and show up on the pages and then after the expiry time , it will be removed, and might the new alert after that date will show up automatically. but also other methods static date calculation will also work , in case it's just a temp text and nothing other gonna comes. i know , it can be a overkill , but something new to learn?

Answer (score 0):

Code: (replace "SomeDate" with the current time, like Aug 4 2016 15:04:00)

```
if(strtotime("now")<strtotime("SomeDate +1month")) echo "Please read a new rulebook";
```

Comment: `strtotime('now')` would be better as just `time()`.